# Change CSS values dynamically with passed in hex color when application loads

Tags: angular

My application is initialized by a redirect that occurs. The application url has query parameters attached to it and I must retrieve and use them when the application loads. One of the parameters is a hex value that must be applied to control the applications primary color theme. Currently I am grabbing the parameters using ActiveRoute queryParams and using them.

I am applying the colors in a file called theme.scss with my other SASS files and is being imported into my main app component which adds all those styles to the DOM in a style tag.

My styles are basically applied as follows:

```
.sidebar-left-item.active {
  background-color: $pirmary-light;
}

.btn-pirmary-light {
  background-color: $pirmary-light;
}
```

The variable $primary-light is the variable that needs the hex value coming in from the redirect applied to it. So it can really be any color.

How can I achieve this kind of behavior? Thanks for any advice.

***Update:***

Here is what I would like to do. With Angular 1 I made a directive that does the following. I would add it to the body tag of the index.html and it would go take care of the bindings and it the end leave valid CSS rules in a style tag. This allowed me to have properties applied at runtime.

**HTLM:**

```
<dynamic-styles id="dynamic-styles" class="ng-cloak">

  #ad-container:before {
    background-color: {{ design.bgAlph }};
  }

</dynamic-styles>
```

**Angular Directive:**

```
dynamicStyles = function($interpolate, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $timeout(function() {
        var domElement = element[0];
        // General interpolation digest cycle will take part after the directive
        // is executed. Separate text interpolation allows not to wait for it,
        // and apply dynamic styles as soon as possible.
        var interpolatedFn = $interpolate(goog.dom.getTextContent(
            domElement));
        goog.dom.setTextContent(domElement, '');
        var styleElement = goog.dom.createElement(goog.dom.TagName.STYLE);
        goog.dom.setTextContent(styleElement, interpolatedFn(scope));
        goog.dom.appendChild(document.head, styleElement);
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

SASS / SCSS is compiled into CSS, so there's no way you can change dynamically the content of a variable because CSS don't have variables.

But possible solution I can think for now is :

**case 1:**
Have the files on hand that you want to edit.

Store these variables as a string, and use `.replace()` to search and replace variables / values

Output this string and then start compilation of css

**case 2:**
using same `.replace()` search and replace css file directly (if possible)!

Once done with one of above steps then only page load should start!

or else some food for your thoughts

[Making Sass talk to JavaScript with JSON](https://css-tricks.com/making-sass-talk-to-javascript-with-json/)

[SassyJSON: Talk to the browser!](http://hugogiraudel.com/2014/01/20/json-in-sass/)

[Sharing Data Between Sass and JavaScript with JSON](https://www.viget.com/articles/sharing-data-between-sass-and-javascript-with-json)

Comment: Is there a way to do this by declaring the color properties somewhere else in the javascript and not doing it in the SCSS files?

Comment: there are several ways to do it..Just let me know your exact scenario, so that I can tell you the solution accordingly!

Comment: I updated the post with the method I used to do this in Angular 1. I am trying to figure out how to do this with angular two but have not yet been successful.

Comment: Im attempting to do this by mimicking interpolation with some method I found in a blog. http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/pawel/2016/04/angular-2-interpolation-service.html

Comment: Im not sure if you had any ideas about ngStyle, but I did not want to do that because that would mean I would have to add this binding to every location that needs to use the variable, so it is not scalable. At least with the directive above I was able to keep all the styles in the body tag rather than them being split up in all the different components.